# How to get complete Port details of running Container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am learning Docker as a beginner and I am finding one info confusing. Here is step details:

1. Pulling Image from Docker Hub
2. Running Image

Now, I am seeing any Half port details in CLI due to which I am not able to ger proper port ID.

But when I am running same Image through KITEMATIC and checking the status of the running container then it is showing me properly.

Please refer Screenshot below for details:

[image]

First Line in shared Pic is showing complete details of PORTs( started container in KITEMATIC)
Second-line is not showing complete.

I want to know the reason for this difference and how to resolve it.

Comment: Can you include the text output of `docker ps` and not a screen shot?  What command did you run to start the container?

Answer (score 1):

Images can expose a port. This is documentation from the image creator to those using the image. It tells you which ports the application inside the container are listening on by default. When you run a container with an exposed port, but you do not publish it on the host, you'll see only the container port listed in the `docker container ls`. This is again only documentation at this point, no docker networking has been configured to use that container port, so docker is letting you know that inside the container that application is likely listening on that port:

```
$ docker run -d --name unpublished --rm nginx
63291688813a75a8d9f0d383b4fbef30e93be8e89bd22fc80c2953da65d1d5e9

$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES 
63291688813a        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   41 seconds ago      Up 39 seconds       80/tcp                     unpublished
```

If you publish a container to a specific port, you'll see that listed as desired:

```
$ docker run -d --name exact -p 8080:80 --rm nginx
10f82a87d8dce2226c030ca5f23e7983b0f60673c0ec614302dc129dad4ba86d

$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
10f82a87d8dc        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   14 seconds ago      Up 12 seconds       0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp       exact
```

And it looks like kitematic is publishing all ports with the `-P` flag (capital) which looks at all exposed ports and maps them to unused high numbered ports:

```
$ docker run -d --name publish_all -P --rm nginx
982afb237756e543820810cbd6366c8fa8569a386ff581cd7edc63557004e8c4

$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
982afb237756        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   3 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds        0.0.0.0:32768->80/tcp      publish_all
```

If you want the know what port was published on the host, particularly when you tell docker to use unused high numbered ports, you can query that with the `port` command, e.g. for the `publish_all` container above:

```
$ docker container port publish_all 80
0.0.0.0:32768
```

You can see the exposed ports with an inspect of the image:

```
$ docker image inspect nginx --format '{{json .Config.ExposedPorts}}' | jq .
{
  "80/tcp": {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In first line of `docker ps`, you publish the port using below command

```
docker run -it -p 32773:80 -p 32772:443 static-site
```

That is why you are seeing `HOST_PORT->Container_PORT`, to see the same response on another container you need to publish port

```
docker run -it --rm -p 80:80 -p 443:443 your_image
```

`80:80` mean `HostPort:ContainerPort`.